# Angular Control Value Accessor: Consider validators of outer form control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a ControlValueAccessor, which is used as a "chips input list". The values will be saved in a FormArray and the resulting value for the outer formControl will be a string array.
The stackblitz-example is very minimal. All actions are implemented in a very basic form.
My main problem is the following:

The CVA implements the Valdiator interface. Therefore if any of the FormArray items is invalid, the validate() function will return a ValidationError.
The invalid item will be highlighted in the template. Furthermore the whole component will be highlighted as invalid, if any of the inner items is invalid.

```
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return this.formArray.invalid ? { invalidItem: true } : null;
  }
  
  <div class="outer-border" [class.invalid]="formArray.invalid">...</div>
```

This works as expected.

But now I want to connect my outer form control definition with the CVA child input.
The outer FormControl has also an validator set:

```
fc = new FormControl<string[]>(['test 1'], Validators.required); // at least one item must exist
<app-custom-input [formControl]="fc" [itemValidators]="itemValidators"></app-custom-input> // template
```

At least one list item must exist, otherwise the form control is invalid. If no item is inserted, I want to display the error in the CVA aswell.

I want something as the following:

currently:

```
  <div class="outer-border" [class.invalid]="formArray.invalid">...</div>
```

target:

```
  <div class="outer-border" [class.invalid]="formArray.invalid ||<OUTER_NG_CONTROL>.invalid">...</div>
```

In short: I want to display the red border, even if no inner item is defined. Therefore I have to access the parent FormControl's state.

But at the current state, I cannot determine the state of the outer form control inside the CVA.
But how to access the outer form control here?

Maybe there is a better approach for the whole implementation?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eugpfe?file=src%2Fmain.ts